# NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass (test failure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I get a failure (in premailer-rails) saying this:

```
ActionMailer::Base delivery delivers email with inlined CSS
     Failure/Error: body = mail.html_part.body.to_s

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/integration/delivery_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's `spec/integration/delivery_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'ActionMailer::Base delivery' do
  it 'delivers email with inlined CSS' do
    WelcomeMailer.welcome_email("world").deliver_now

    mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    expect(mail).to be_present
    body = mail.html_part.body.to_s
    expect(body).to be_present
    expect(body).to include(%{<p style="font-size: 12px;">Hello world</p>})
  end
end
```

Not sure what's happening; why is there a NoMethodError? :/

Answer (score 0):

`html_part` is set if you send a multipart email, you can call `mail.body.to_s` instead, it should be set.